# Iterate on the columns of a row in MongoDB Map Reduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

My Mongo schema is as follows:

- KEY: Client ID
- Value: { Location1: Bitwise1, Location2: Bitwise2, ...}

So the Column names would be names of locations. This data represents the locations to which a client has been to, and bitwise captures the days for which the client was present at that location.

I'd like to run a map-reduce query on the above schema. In that, I'd like to iterate on all the columns of the Value for a Row. How can that be done? Could some one give a small code snipped which explains it clearly? I'm having a hard time finding it on web.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object/684692#684692 is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Also, the terms you are using aren't right for MongoDb, there's a handy table here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/